# Powering 4 servos with an external source

Tags: arduino-uno, servo

I am powering 4 tower pro sg90's and I NEED them to run at maximum torque for at least a few minutes, so 4.8volts. I am wondering how many AA batteries I will need to power all 4 servos at maximum torque for a short amount of time (like 5minutes type of thing). The servos are basically lifting different 3d printed objects.

Comment: Well, theoretically that should work, so what is the problem? You want something mobile? You'll most likely need batteries or an accu-pack.

Comment: @Paul Oh there isnt really a problem, just looking for other suggestions :) Havent bought the 4x AA holders yet, as its easter! Happy easter by the way!!

Comment: Okay, (Arduino) StackExchange is aimed on helping people who run into problems. We prefer questions that can be answered and that aren't to broad. Your question should give more of a clue on what you're trying to achieve etc. You could/should also do some research yourself.

Comment: Welcome to Arduino SE.  Be sure to take the tour at https://arduino.stackexchange.com/Tour

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**When choosing a power source, you'll have to consider a few requirements:**

- Required max amperage (max draw of power)
- Required voltages (AC or DC, and available voltages)
- Does it have to be mobile?

  - How long does it have to be powered? (how to recharge/refuel?)

Also see this [tutorial](https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/how-to-power-a-project) it explains that you need a certain voltage for a device to work, too high voltage can result in permanent damage. For amperage, you need to have at least the minimal required, too much is no problem.

Since you don't really have a problem to fix, I can only tell you what I've worked with or what I've liked.

**Bench supplies**

Bench supplies are great while prototyping, they don't run out (like batteries) and can have a large range of voltage and supply a lot of power. I've looked around to get a nice bench power supply, but I found that they're quite expensive. If you want a variable supply that can do up to 5A, it'll cost you some real money (though it usually is well worth it).

Though my setup has always worked great for me, I use:

- [converted PSU](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5TJaREOi1SY) (PC power supply)
- [Adjustable step down module](http://www.ebay.com/itm/5A-Adjustable-CC-CV-Display-Step-Down-charge-Module-LED-Panel-Voltmeter-Ammeter-/401092492732?hash=item5d62f9bdbc:g:Vj4AAOSw-0xYeX~n)

For the PSU, you could also add indicator LED's, they're great because they can supply very much power at very convenient voltages (12v, 5v, 3.3v, -12v). Also since it's a PSU it has overcurrent protection and thus is reasonably safe.

I've also bought the "adjustable step down module" from E-bay, you can power it from a 24V or 19V source like a laptop charger. You can set the output voltage and output max amperage. You can even see when the supply is limiting on power or on amperage. (So you can check if your device is taking more current than set)

**"Moving" projects**

The easiest thing here is (multiple) batteries, check the tutorial of sparkfun again. If you put them in series, you will sum up the voltage. If you put them in parallel, you will sum up the capacity.

I think batteries are the easiest way to power your device. You can [check different types of batteries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_battery_sizes), they have different voltages and "ampere hours". Battery holders are cheap and you can easily replace them if they run out.

On the subject of rechargeables, I would go with an Ni-Mh pack. I've got a Ni-Mh pack for airsoft and it's very reliable and easy to charge. Li-Ion requires much more care in handling and charging.

Other options can be solar-cells or other harvestable energy, but these often aren't really viable.

**Extra**

When starting to move, a servo can suddenly pull a lot of power. Not all supplies can handle this well. So the other servo's may "jiggle". Often, it's good to have a capacitor that can act as a "reservoir" or for smoothing. Same goes with devices that reset in some scenario's.

*I hope this gives you an idea on some possibilities, I haven't highlighted all options (there are too many), you should check tutorials/video's and see what works for you.

For example, check [this instructable](http://www.instructables.com/id/Powering-your-project/) that focusses on some (analog) points that I didn't mention.*

Comment: Thanks for replying, i am following the sparkfun article; The batteries i am using are 2100mAh so 2.1A for one hour (which is enough for my project), and the battery supplies 1.5V. This gives a total power of 3.15W for one battery. The servos I am using have a stall current of 600mA and a stall torque of 4.8V, which = 2.88W and11.52W for all 4 servos. so 11.52W/3.15W = 3.67, so does this mean that it should be sufficient to use 4 of my AA batteries to power my servos

Comment: You'll need 3x batteries in series, to get the 4.5V. If the batteries can discharge at 1C (2,1A) and 4x 0,6 = 2,4A you really are on the low end. Maybe two rows of three in series. But a lot of accupacks are made for RC applications and fall inbetween the min/max of servo's and can deliver enough power. (If it's on a table next to your 3D printer, why not use a 5V adapter?)